# Updating then displaying

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if I do something wrong it is my first time using stackflow and just beginning php and mysql.

The problem I am getting is that the table updates AFTER it echos. I would like to display the updated table.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $bids = $row['bids']; 
  $bids +=1; 
  mysql_query("UPDATE items SET bids = " .$bids.", cost=" . $price. " WHERE items.name =". $item ); 

  echo "<tr>
          <td>".$row['name']."</td>
          <td align=\"right\">".$row['cost']."</td>
          <td align=\"right\">".$row['bids']."</td>
          <td align=\"right\">".$row['seller_name']."</td>
        </tr>";  
}//end while
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more line in between your update statement and display statement.

```
$new_record = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.name =". $item"));
```

Then use your echo statement as :

```
echo "<tr><td>".$new_record ['name']."</td>
     <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['cost']."</td>
     <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['bids']."</td>
     <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['seller_name']."</td>
   </tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select rows from the table again, if You want to show them after update. In the code snippet above You actually `echo`s old entries from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in an if block

```
if(mysql_query("UPDATE items SET bids = " .$bids.", cost=" . $price. " WHERE items.name =". $item )){
  echo "<td>".$new_record ['name']."</td>
  <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['cost']."</td>
  <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['bids']."</td>
  <td align=\"right\">".$new_record['seller_name']."</td>
 </tr>";
}
```